# Least squares of parabola in c#

Tags: c#, regression, numerical-methods, least-squares

I want to apply **Least squares method** for a set of 2D points f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C.
I am **using C#** and ***not allowed to use 3rd party*** or any external code. Can you please help me in finding a function that receives the x and y arrays of experimental data and returns the best fitted A,B,C values.
Solving the general case is more than welcomed :), i.e providing one file/class that contains all functions that needed to do linear regression.

Comment: [Levenberg-Marquardt.NET](http://kniaz.net/software/LMA.aspx) Download the zip file, open it, navigate to LMA, and open the LMA file. You can see the class which is used. Don't plagiarise though, just get an idea on how to do it. I don't think there is an internal library for this.

Comment: Many thanks for prompt reply. It is indeed nice code that one can learn from it a lot. However, I am looking for self-contained function that I can embed in my code.